# How can I put a trigger on a system table to gather historical data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, log-shipping, triggers

I'm able to implement trigger on user define table but not on system table (`log_shipping_primaries` and `log_shipping_secondaries`), it store info about when the backup `.bak` file was generated and when the transaction log ship file `.trn` file was copied and restored at secondary database

Objective : to implement RPO (recovery point objective) > 15 min at secondary database (DR site)

I was given a task to monitor `log_shipping activities` and provide historical data to higher management. Now the problem is these 2 tables is that it updates the old entry (for a given database) every time whenever a new entry is added.

Solution (does not work in SQL Server 2000):  whenever a new entry is inserted, insert the similar data in user define table via trigger so as to keep historical data.

1. how to implement trigger on system table (what permission do I need) or is it possible at all (please be precidse)?
2. alternative to trigger like stored procedure or something(I've no experience in stored procedure)

Answer (score 1):

If you using SQL job for backup and transaction log shipping, in that case you can add a step before that to import that data in history table.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to create triggers on system tables.

I'd look at adding a job to [SQL Server Agent](http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/tutorial/sql_server_agent.cfm) that runs at whatever frequency is appropriate (say, every 30 seconds)

Comment: thanks for your reply,just one query
some system table allow triggers(log_shipping_history), can anyone suggest some script to figure out which system table allow triggers

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a job to save the data from the table before each backup? As for how to do this, it's your choice really. Write a stored procedure, write an insert statement directly into a SQL Agent job, sit by your computer and hit F5 every 15 minutes... :-) Lots of options.